# Stuck at getting started with message broker Apache Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm trying to setup a broker with Python for my assignment.

I want a broker that can get data from a consumer, and send them to a broker and reverse. This needs to happen in real time (that's why Apache Kafka), but I can't find any guides / tutorials on this subject. Who can guide me in the right direction?

Comment: This is unfortunatelly the wrong place for your question. there are for sure other more appropriate places for that. Please take a look at the Stackoverflow guidelines of what makes a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Plenty of guides exist for running Kafka (just look at the official website). Plenty of **other** guides exist for how to install and use python libraries with Kafka (again, the official sites or github for those libraries)... You're going to have to show where exactly you are stuck

Comment: Secondly, Kafka is not the only option for "real-time" interactions, and brokers do not "get data from consumers" in Kafka terminology - producers send data; consumers read data

Answer (score 0):

apache kafka is written in scala and java. if you need to write kafka clients in python, you could use [kafka-python 2.0.2 library](https://pypi.org/project/kafka-python/)